# Prove, that $ K $ needn't be normal subgroup of $ G $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose, that $ K $ is normal subgroup of $ N $, and $ N $ is also normal subgroup of $ G $. Prove, that $ K $ needn't be normal subgroup of $ G $. I can give only counter-example?

Comment: "*mustn't*" makes the statement incorrect. You mean "*needn't*".

Comment: Although the question isn't very well posed, you are being asked to produce groups $K \lhd N \lhd G$ with $K \not \lhd G.$

Comment: @ZevChonoles thank you. Ok, so if I give counter-example it will be enough?

Comment: @Mat The proposed duplicate question gives more details than I would have given. You are lucky.

Comment: @MarkBennet But I had counter-example :), I asked only about if this enough :)

Comment: And unfortunately I haven't found this topic before, so I must only asked :).

Comment: If you can produce an example where $K$ is not normal in $G$ then you have proved what you were asked to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the group $A_4$ - the alternating group on four elements. This has a normal subgroup $V$ of order $4$ which is abelian. $V$ has three subgroups of order $2$, all of which are normal (since $V$ is abelian). But $A_4$ has no normal subgroup of order 2.

I'll leave you to fill in the details, since you have given no indication of your own effort on the problem.